# Am I using a ManyToMany mapping in JPA properly?

Tags: java, database, jpa

I am working on a school project, and the goal is to make a JavaEE application for a fictional pharmacy.

Since one drug can cure one or many diseases and one disease can be treated by one or many drugs, I figured it is a `@OneToMany` relation on the `Drug` side and a `@ManyToMany` on the `Disease` side.
I also have a `Patient` entity. A patient may suffer from one or many diseases, and one disease may afflict many patients. I coded my classes as follows but I get an incompatible-mapping-exception between my `Drug` and `Disease` classes when I try to generate tables from entities. I am using a  GlassFish  server and a Derby connection in Eclipse (everything is well-configured, so it's definitely a code issue). My classes are as follows:

```
public class Drug implements Serializable{
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Disease.class, mappedBy = "Cures_For_This_Disease")
private List<Disease> Diseases_Cured_By_This_Drug;
//other fields such as the name, price and origin of the drug
}

public class Disease implements Serializable{
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Drug.class)
private List<Drug> Cures_For_This_Disease;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Patient.class)
private List<Patient> Afflicted_Patients;
//other fields such as name of disease etc.
}

public class Patient implements Serializable{
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Disease.class, mappedBy = "AfflictedPatients")
private List<Disease> Current_Diseases;
//other fields such as Patient name, social sec. nubmer etc
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "but I get an incompatible-mapping-exception" Post those exceptions here.

Comment: My classes are named in Serbian, but here's the translation:
Lek = Drug,
Oboljenje = Disease,
Pacijent = Patient 
http://pastebin.com/wBFa8YwU

Comment: Drug <-> Disease is many to many, but you have @OneToMany on Drug

Comment: @guido So, you're saying both sides should be many to many? Is any extra annotation needed, like `@JoinTable`?

Comment: ManyToOne is OneToMany on the other side; ManyToMany is ManyToMany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `@ManyToMany` annotation in `Drug` and `Patient` classes.

```
public class Drug implements Serializable{
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Disease> Diseases_Cured_By_This_Drug;

}

public class Disease implements Serializable{
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="Diseases_Cured_By_This_Drug")
    private List<Drug> Cures_For_This_Disease;
}
```

This should create a join table between the two corresponding tables.